# How to show an iPhone app on iPad with retina display graphics?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an iPhone app and upgraded the target for iPad in Xcode. But now, the app launches in the upper left corner of the iPad very small only. I want to scale it up to the iPad screen but then use the retina display graphics.

There's a lot of code that positions the views on screen. Is there an simple way to let an iPhone app appear x2 on the iPad using the retina display graphics?

Comment: Accept some answers to your questions, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try checking for ‘[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]‘ and manually loading the proper graphics yourself.

In iOS 4, on the iPhone 4 or the iPod 4th gen, a graphic that ends in @2x will automatically load in place of the low res version.

As Stellian pointed out, the iPad does not just autoload retina graphics. Once you are going through the trouble, you may as well just make an iPad UI.

Comment: You'll also have do double the size of all your views too. This is far from "simple".

Comment: @robot k - on iPhone 4 or iPad? On iphone 4, the phone handles native controls by itself.

Comment: You're correct. I meant on the iPad. Simply loading the double sized images won't actually double the size of the app on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible to use the Retina Display graphics on the iPad at the moment. I remember something about a Radar a guy opened about this issue and asked the other devs to dupe it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but that's all about memory. iPad has twice less than iPhone4. So do that to play, not to release.